# How to show progress bar before we jump and reverse to another page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Before i ask this question, i have tried to make progress bar with css and jquery. But the result is just before page loaded fully the progress bar is shown and it was not satisfactory.

I want to make progress bar, not just before page loaded fully, but its load before we jump or reverse to another page.

The example is like Github or Youtube.

How can i make the progress bar like that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can we see your code? My gut is you're putting the bar code in `$(document).ready()` rather than `$(window).load()`

Comment: I using nprogress.js as progress bar and the javascript is `NProgress.start();NProgress.done();` so how to make before jump and reverse to another page?